# Deleting photos from Resource Path

Tags: iphone

Iam developing an applicaton in which iam saving the picture taken from photo library into resource. Now i want to delete the photo from resource path how can i do that there is some function for deleting the photos from resource?

Answer (score 2):

[`[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:@"path_to_your_photo" error:NULL];`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW21)